# Get area type (Forest/Street/Water) of a location on android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

In my app on android I have google maps included. Now I want to get information about the area around you. Eg, are you in a park/forest/at the beach... 
So I basicly want a function that answers the input coordinates 53°33'40.9"N 10°00'05.1"E with "water". Google maps has these information, but I didn't see a way to get them.
I know that there is a database for europe (forgot the name right now) but is there also something for the whole world?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Place api will help you to know about particular place  [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows)